# Android 23 and smaller don't fill all screen in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, landscape

I make an app which uses dynamic tables, my XML code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="none">

<include
    android:id="@id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/action_bar">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:stretchColumns="*">

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The table take all values from code. My problem is that in Android 23 and less, when you put screen orientation in landscape mode, the screen looks like:

[image: landscape 23]

But in Android version 24 and above, the screen looks good:

[image: landscape 24]

P.D: `match_parent` property don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's displaying different, from what I can understand it's displaying as it should be considering the layout attributes (i.e. all wrap_content), there is nothing to indicate it should fill the parent.
However changing the fillViewPort attribute of the horizontal ScrollView and it's width to match_parent do the trick work.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport

```
    ...
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If work for someone, the solution was change `RelativeLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout` and change `HorizontalScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    android:id="@id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```